# Exploit for a CSRF to a POST server with specific "Accept" header?

Tags: exploit, csrf

Say the attacker owns a domain, `attacker.com`. Attacker wants to create a webpage on it to make a CSRF attack toward the `victim.com` server. The targeted page is `victim.com/target.php` which only accepts POST request, with a specific `Accept` header of, say, `application/x-foo`.

With such setup, I couldn't find a way for the attacker to craft a CSRF page:

- If attacker does a `<form action="victim.com/target.php" method="POST">` then I see no way for the attacker to set the `Accept` header and so the `target.php` file won't do any action
- If the attacker makes a `const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/x-foo');` then the browser preflights a CORS request `OPTIONS` to the `target.php` which responds nothing (because it's not `POST`) and so the browser won't make the CSRF request
- The attacker cannot use a URL-based CSRF (like `victim.com/target.php?param=xyz`) becausse it's not POST either
- Attacker does not own the `victim.com` server so they cannot put a non-cross-domain XHR inb there

Even tho I cannot find an exploit, it feels very unlikely to me that a simple check such as `($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] !== 'application/x-foo')` in the victim's webpage is enough to prevent any CSRF attack... still, I see no exploit?!

It seems very close to [OWASP's custom header CSRF prevention](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#use-of-custom-request-headers) but Accept is not custom: does this change a thing?

Comment: See the note regarding additional restrictions to `Accept` in some browsers in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests) and make sure you use a browser which is not affected by these restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests) [documentation](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header)[1], the `accept` header is a "CORS-safelisted request header" and therefore should not trigger a preflight. Thus, checking for that header (unless the server requires an [invalid character](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-unsafe-request-header-byte) in it) should not be sufficient to prevent CSRF.

Non-simple requests get pre-flighted, but "simple" (safelisted) ones do not. As long as your server doesn't send back CORS response headers that permit the preflighted CORS request to proceed, and there's no way to make a valid simple request, that works.

[1] Thank you for the link, @Steffen Ullrich

Comment: Indeed, that surprised me but the test case I was studying got a typo I didn't notice at first look: ` xhrPost.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-from-urlencoded');` "from"... So you're right, the `xhrPost.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/foo');` wasn't involved, and thanks for the resources links